# Nested Boost Fusion Structs

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

Is it possible to define (or adapt) a Boost Fusion struct that contains member Boost Fusion structs in a single statement?

For example, how can I adapt or define something equivalent to this:

```
struct Outer
{
   int i;
   float j;
   struct Nested
   { 
      int a;
   } nested;
};
```

Where both `Outer` and `Outer::Nested` are reflectable types.

Defining all the internal types in inside-out order is very messy and exposes internal types externally.

Comment: example of what you want? (even if psuedo code?)

Comment: Is [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kfcBTaL8ZuyzxBtr) something you'd be interested in? (If it is I could write an answer tomorrow). I know it would be better to use BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT but I can't see a way to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: @jv_ : that would be slightly better than the pure fusion solution, but I would have really preferred a single definition point as with BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT. Writing your suggestion as an answer might help future posters too though.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to 'define' the inner struct using its fully qualified name:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  Outer::Nested,
  a
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
  Outer,
  i,
  j,
  nested
)
```

Comment: OK, so this is adapting the struct inside-out, or more specifically, adapting the inner class separately from the out class. 
Is there a way to do it with `BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT` and in a single definition?

Comment: _That_'s what you mean :)

Comment: Well, this achieves the proper types, but it is not a single statement the syntactically looks similar to the struct definition.

Comment: note that in order to match with the question's code, one of the fields in this answer should be `j` instead of `f` (couldn't edit the post because it's a too short difference)